# SQL Query Incorrect Format in Bash - Not in Frame

Tags: postgresql, bash

I am performing an SQL query in bash like this:

```bash
updated_records="select class, subject, teacher  from main_a where date(updated_at) = '2024-03-07';"
```

after running the query I am getting the results like this

```
class | subject | teacher -----------+-----------+--------- A123 | maths | John A234 | chemistry | matt goldberg  | bio chemistry  | Hannah  (3 rows)
```

Please help me to get the correct results, in the following format:

```
class      | subject   | teacher 
-----------+-----------+--------- 
A123       | maths     | John 
A234       | chemistry | matt goldberg 
           | biology   |  Hannah
```

Comment: There's a chance that the results you get back actually *do* conform with your expectations, and you just fail to capture and/or print them correctly. Please elaborate on "after running the query I am getting the results like this". What code do you use to run the query? What code do you use to capture the results? What code do you use to print what you have captured? How did you get from "the query" to "results like this"?

Answer (score 0):

I would set `IFS` empty to avoid losing the newlines:

```bash
IFS=''
result=$(psql -c "SELECT ...")
```

Answer (score -1):

you include case statement to replace specific subject values:

updated_records=$(sqlite database.db <<EOF
SELECT class,
CASE
WHEN subject = 'bio chemistry' THEN 'biology'
ELSE subject
END AS subject,
teacher
FROM main_a
WHERE date(updated_at) = '2024-03-07';
EOF
)

Comment: You have correctly spotted that OP's actual output and the one they expect differ in the single item of `bio chemistry` vs. `biology`, but this is probably just an accidental inconsistency. According to the question's title ("Incorrect Format"), their main issue is more likely the absence of newlines which breaks the formatting. (Also, the question is tagged `postgresql`, not `sqlite`.)